# PHP - Make outlook or Mac Calender appointment

Tags: php, calendar

I was just wondering and searching the internet. Is it possible to create an appointment via mail and send it as an attachement so you can save it on your calenders client.

And is it possible within PHP? If so, can anyone give me an example or tutorial?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-Type: text/Calendar");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=calendar.ics");
echo "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
echo "VERSION:2.0\n";
echo "PRODID:-//Foobar Corporation//NONSGML Foobar//EN\n";
echo "METHOD:REQUEST\n"; // requied by Outlook
echo "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
echo "UID:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."-".rand()."-example.com\n"; // required by Outlok
echo "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."\n"; // required by Outlook
echo "DTSTART:20080413T000000\n"; 
echo "SUMMARY:TEST\n";
echo "DESCRIPTION: this is just a test\n";
echo "END:VEVENT\n";
echo "END:VCALENDAR\n";
```

http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/04/14/generate-outlook-calendar-events-with-php-and-icalendar/

You can replace the info with get variables to make dynamic links.